# Crossfading with NAudio

Tags: naudio

I want to do crossfading with NAudio and my first approach was, to use two WaveOut devices (IWavePlayer) simultaneously. This works very well. I can play, stop, fadeout and fadein each WaveOut individually.

Now I discovered the MixingSampleProvider and I thinks it's a better approach to use this.

But how can I individually stop one file while the other one continues to play (and vice versa) when I use the MixingSampleProvider?

Answer (score 0):

In my perception, you can't because is the same provider.

My solution for this is a play-and-dead function with callbacks for audio with id, position ad length. So, you can check the desired position for cross and starting play other file when the first finish the remain content.

I hope helped you. Sorry my bad english.